# Electon.Net blazor app not showing window

Tags: electron, blazor, .net-5

I'm trying to use Electron.net for my Blazor project on my Mac.

I'm struggling to get the whole project working properly (I think so). As I found out, when I run

```
electronize start
```

The process hangs on listening to ports:

```
  MyApp -> /Users/...path_to_my_app.../obj/Host/bin/
  node_modules missing in: /Users/...path_to_my_app.../obj/Host/node_modules
  Start npm install...
  removed 1 package, changed 3 packages, and audited 186 packages in 9s
  found 0 vulnerabilities
        ElectronHostHook handling started...
  Invoke electron - in dir: /Users/...path_to_my_app.../obj/Host/node_modules/.bin
  Electron Socket IO Port: 8000
  Electron Socket started on port 8000 at 127.0.0.1
  ASP.NET Core Port: 8001
```

And it's basically stuck there.

Then when I run

```
electronize start /watch
```

all opens just fine (strangely, both the app window as well as Safari open...)

```
ElectronHostHook handling started...
Invoke electron - in dir: /Users/...PATH.../obj/Host/node_modules/.bin
Electron Socket IO Port: 8000
Electron Socket started on port 8000 at 127.0.0.1
ASP.NET Core Watch Port: 8001
stdout: watch : 
stdout: Started
stdout: Génération...
stdout: Use Electron Port: 8000
stdout: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
stdout:       Now listening on: http://localhost:8001
stdout: ASP.NET Core host has fully started.
stdout: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Content root path: /Users/...PATH...
ASP.NET Core Application connected... global.electronsocket J5mifH5-zThaphv4AAAA 2021-03-26T11:46:16.995Z
stdout: BridgeConnector connected!
stdout: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
  Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

So I suspect my app's setup is somehow corrupt - couldn't find out where though.

Technical specs:

```
MacOS Big Sur (v11.2.3)
.Net 5.0
Electron v 9.4.4
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your app manually from ...\bin\Desktop\<your-os-name>?

Comment: By the way, does electronize build command return any errors?

Comment: @ZhuravlevA. Yep, I did. I was eventually able to get it working by deleting all obj and bin folders and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same behavior myself and discovered that it can be caused by your web application throwing a *runtime error* prior to the call to `ElectronNET.API.Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync` in `Startup.cs`. In my case, the app would build without issue, it was the error early on that caused the launcher to hang without any feedback.

So one solution may be to run `dotnet run` in the web app directory and make sure you can load the app in a regular browser.

Comment: I actually found out that updating NodeJS and updating Electron via the command `dotnet tool update --global ElectronNET.CLI` actually helped!